# checkbox select all toggle function

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkboxes and the first checkbox value is select all. My jQuery code is

```
$(".checkboxFilter input:checkbox:first").change().toggle(function () {
        alert("inside first toggle");
        $(".checkboxFilter").find(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    }, function () {
        alert("inside second toggle");
        $(".checkboxFilter").find(':checkbox').prop("checked", false);
    });
```

The issue is when I render the page, by default the select all button is checked but no other options are checked. When i click the select all checkbox again it selects all and when i click the select all button once more it deselects all but the select all button still remains checked. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `toggle`, just `change` will work. Take a look at this

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5hXN2/)**

```
$(".checkboxFilter input:checkbox:first").change(function () {
        $(".checkboxFilter").find(':checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Worked ! Thank you. Was stuck with this since morning :(

Comment: Could you explain how does it remove the checked buttons when I click "select all" (i.e first checkbox ) second time ?

Comment: In the change event handler I am just setting the `first`(Select All) checkbox `checked` property to all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the default state of "Select All" to non checked or everything to checked.

Comment: I added another checkbox "Unselect all" and fulfiled the requirement. I tried making select all unchecked or checked in the beginning but same error came up.